# R: Creating a new column based on existing conditions for first 150 rows only, and per participant?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data from 50 participants who completed a task. Each person completed 450 trials which were separated into 3 blocks (150 trials per block; these were the experimental conditions). Conditions were "happy", "sad" and "neutral", and were presented to participants in a random order. Each individual participants data is currently merged into an overall dataframe, looking a bit like below:

| participant | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | neutral |
| 1 | neutral |
| 1 | neutral |
| (...) | neutral |
| 2 | happy |
| 2 | happy |
| 2 | happy |
| (...) | happy |

I'd like to create a new column called order that stores the first condition block that participants completed. So if they completed the neutral block first, for this to be coded as 1, if it was the happy block, then for this to be coded as 2, and if it was the sad block, for this to be coded as 3.

As there are 450 trials in total, and I am only interested in the first 150 (the first condition block), I have tried the following code:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>%
  slice(1:150) %>% 
  if(condition == "neutral"){
    dat$order <- 1
  } else if(condition == "happy"){
    dat$order <- 2
  } else if(condition == "sad"){
    dat$order <- 3
  }
```

However, this returns the following error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: `match(condition, c("neutral","happy","sad"))` (inside a mutate) will give you the ints you need, much faster (~30x) than `case_when` or just about any other approach.

Comment: How many rows should the output have per participant, 1, 150, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rows are ordered chronologically, you could use `group_by` to process each participant separately, `summarize` to get one row per participant, with the first condition,  then `mutate` and `case_when` to map the text values to the coded values.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
    group_by(participant) %>%
    summarize(condition = first(condition)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(
        order = case_when(
            condition == "neutral" ~ 1, 
            condition == "happy" ~ 2, 
            condition == "sad" ~ 3
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the 150 values of the condition occur together you can check only the `first` value for each participant instead of 150.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(order = case_when(first(condition) == "neutral" ~ 1, 
                           first(condition) == "happy" ~ 2, 
                           first(condition) == "sad" ~ 3)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

V hard to know without a reprex for us to work with, but one idea:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= 150) %>%
  mutate(order = case_when(
    condition == "neutral" ~ 1,
    condition == "happy" ~ 2,
    condition == "sad" ~ 3
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

`if()` isn't vectorized, it is used when you want to check a single value. `ifelse()` or `dplyr::case_when()` are good options for vectorized comparisons. You also have the issue that you're passing the whole data frame to `if()`. If you are trying to create a new column in `dplyr`, use `mutate`. I would suggest

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>%
  slice(1:150) %>% 
  mutate(
    order = case_when(
      condition == "neutral" ~ 1,
      condition == "happy" ~ 2,
      condition == "sad" ~ 3
    )
  )
```